# Loading Bulk Images using way too much ram

Tags: c#

When I run the following code I insert 1,5 GB jpg images in to List VideoType but It uses 20GB+ Ram. I suspect about some duplicates but I don't see how?

```
public class VideoType
{
     public int VideoTypeId { get; set; }
     public List<Bitmap> Bitmaps { get; set; }
}
```

CODE >

```
List<VideoType> VideoTypes = new List<VideoType>();

for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    VideoTypes.Add(VideoTypeGet(VideoTypeId)));



public static VideoType VideoTypeGet(int VideoTypeId)
{
         VideoType VideoType = new VideoType();
         List<Bitmap> Bitmaps = new List<Bitmap>()

         for (int i = 1; i < X; i++)
             Bitmaps.Add((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"X"));

         VideoType.Bitmaps = Bitmaps;
         return VideoType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG is compressed. Bitmap is not compressed. So - there you go. The images get decompressed and take up more RAM.

Comment: No. In order to show them they must be decompressed. You can avoid that as long as possible, but then you get the processing time later before showing. Smart - and time intensive - programming and compromises are the only way to work around that stuff. I do not have the use case - so I can not recmmend an architecture (and even if - that is beyond the scope of a Q&A site).